Questions regarding architecture and feasibility for a mobile app using Socket.IO
I'm creating a mobile app in React Native similar to JackBox games, but am unfamiliar with networking. My idea was to use Socket.IO and connect it to a server either on Azure or a local connection (someone else in the room). Is there a way to use a user's phone as the server without connecting to wifi? Regardless of the server connection, can iOS and android devices communicate with each other? Or is there a better way to do this all together? Thanks!


iOS and Android devices can communicate with each other using Socket.IO. Socket.IO is a library that enables real-time, bidirectional communication between web clients and servers. It's cross-platform and can work with any server-side technology, including Node.js, which is commonly used with React Native.

Another option you might consider is using a service like Firebase, which provides real-time database and messaging capabilities. Firebase also has a built-in authentication system, which can be useful for managing user accounts and permissions.

In summary, using Socket.IO with a server on Azure or a local connection is a feasible approach for building a mobile app similar to JackBox games. However, using a user's phone as a server without connecting to Wi-Fi is not recommended. Additionally, Firebase is another option to consider for real-time communication and database management.

Socket.IO: How it works, when to use it, and how to get started : https://ably.com/topic/socketio

How to use with React Native : https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react-native

Building Real-Time Applications with Socket.io, React.js, Node.js, and Express.js: A Comprehensive Guide : https://medium.com/@matheshyogeswaran/building-real-time-applications-with-socket-io-adc86da2f9f1

Is it possible to combine React Native with socket.io : Is it possible to combine React Native with socket.io


